# Objc: getting the state of bool from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a switch in my Prefs from which i'm trying to read its state if TRUE or FALSE from its plist file

I have been trying to do it using this piece of code,

```
NSDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"file.plist"];

BOOL toggle = [[plist objectForKey:@"someToggle"] boolValue];

NSString *aName;

if (toggle) { aName = [plist valueForKey:@"aText"]; }

else { aName = @"some text"; }
```

but it always return to the else why? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Use `boolForKey` instead of `objectForKey`
2) Did you register your settings  If not register it (check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379785/initialize-ios-preferences-from-preference-bundle-on-first-app-load/23379833#23379833)

Comment: What is `plist`? `NSUserDefaults` or `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a value for the `someToggle` key?

Comment: it is a NSDictionary and yes `SomeToggle` is a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first this you want to see is exactly what `[plist objectForKey:@"someToggle"]` is returning. If it is something that NSNumber thinks is 0, it will always evaluate to false.

In addition, Make sure the plist has `<true/>` or `<false/>` as the value.

Comment: Oh man! i had a miss spelling in my plist file name inside `defaults` key. Thanks for telling me to check my plist :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure `[plist objectForKey:@"someToggle"]` is returning an object. If there is a typo, or if for some other reason the plist doesn’t exist or an entry for that key doesn’t exist, the return value of `[plist objectForKey:@"someToggle"]` will always be `nil`, and calling `-boolValue` on `nil` will always return `0`, which will cause `toggle` to have a value of `NO`.